# XmlDocument becomes null after return statement

Tags: c#, xml

I'm making an HttpWebRequest where I'm sending an Xml document to a web service and returning the results from the request to unit tests. After the return statement the Xml Document gets nulled out. Why?

```
public class BaseTest
{
    public XmlDocument _xmlDoc; 

    public string CallWebService()
    {
    XmlDocument _xmlDoc = "./xmlfile.xml";

    /*Prepare HttpHeaders and make webservice call*/

    string result = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    return result;//<-----_xmlDoc becomes null at this point. 

    }

}

[TestMethod]
public void TestWebService()
{
     string result = CallWebService();
     Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("SUCCESS"));  
}
```

Comment: too little information. I think the error is somewhere else

Comment: There are several mistakes in the code

Comment: Turn around, take some deep breaths, think about something happy for five minutes, turn back round, read your question. You seeing our problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
XmlDocument _xmlDoc = "./xmlfile.xml";
```

to

```
_xmlDoc = "./xmlfile.xml";
```

Comment: That was precisely it, the variable got shadowed. Thanks!